Unexpected Network Latency in Google Cloud Run: Long-lived vs Short-lived Connections
I've encountered an unexpected behavior in Google Cloud Run that significantly affects network latency, and I'm seeking insights from the community.
Setup:

Single Google Cloud Run instance handling all traffic
Two types of clients: a chat widget and Facebook Messenger webhook

Issue:
When processing messages from the Facebook Messenger webhook, I observed dramatically increased network latency compared to processing identical messages from the chat widget. The only difference was in how the connections were handled:

Chat Widget:

Sends POST request
Keeps connection alive during processing
Receives response through the same TCP/IP connection


Facebook Messenger Webhook (Initial Implementation):

Receives webhook POST
Sends 200 OK immediately, closing the connection
Processes message asynchronously
Sends response to Facebook Graph API in a separate request



Logs demonstrating the latency difference:
Fbm Logs:
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:31:50.224488Z fetching qr progress
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:32:02.287477Z qr progress fetched
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:32:08.691214Z qr status checked
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:32:15.787925Z msg queued checked
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:32:32.488039Z msg processing set
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:32:32.986875Z new step logged
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:32:32.987111Z mini thread fetched
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:32:33.086821Z mini thread logged

Widget Logs:
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:42.602917Z fetching qr progress
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:42.675074Z qr progress fetched
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:42.741831Z qr status checked
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:42.808483Z msg queued checked
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:43.027842Z msg processing set
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:43.028527Z new step logged
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:43.028686Z mini thread fetched
•   DEFAULT 2024-08-16T21:58:43.028833Z mini thread logged

Resolution:
The issue was resolved by keeping the webhook connection open during message processing, mirroring the behavior of the chat widget.
Questions:

Why does maintaining an open TCP/IP connection significantly impact the performance of other network operations within the same Cloud Run instance?
What mechanisms in Cloud Run or the underlying infrastructure might be causing this behavior?
Are there best practices or configurations in Cloud Run to achieve consistent performance across different connection patterns?

Initial Research:
Possible factors include connection pooling, TCP keep-alive, and Cloud Run's internal scheduling, but I haven't been able to determine the root cause with certainty.
I'd greatly appreciate any insights or explanations from the community regarding this behavior. Understanding the underlying mechanisms would help in optimizing our application and might benefit others facing similar issues in Cloud Run.
EDIT: I have always at least 1 instance running, so it is not a spool-down, spool up issue.

The issue comes from the immediate answer sent to Facebook messenger in the 2nd case. You can have a look to my other answer here to have more details on the reason (CLoud Run design and pricing model)

To solve the issue, you have 2 options:

Set the CPU Always ON option. You will be charged for the entire instance life duration, i.e. 15 minutes after the latest request received, timeout for Google to delete the instance. -> So 15 minutes session max, if no new request is received by the instance.
Do not send the HTTP response to keep the request context up. In that case you can set a max 60 minutes timeout.

In both cases, the ideal solution is to be able to resume the session in case of backend timeout, whatever the solution chosen.

This makes a lot of sense! Thank you @guillaume!

More context - https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation
